# Java Smart GWT listgrid without datasource - filter not working

Tags: java, filter, smartgwt, listgrid

Without Datasource, can we filter listGrid records. I am not able to filter the records. Anyone faced the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be below link help you to understand:

https://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/32647-listgrid-with-no-datasource